# How to plot fuzzy membership function?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, membership, fuzzy

I have this membership function of fuzzy:

```
br =[0  0  0.7802  0.3298  0  0  0  0];
n = [0  0  0  0.6702  0.4397  0  0  0];
bl =[0  0  0  0  0.5603  0.5496  0  0];
```

I want to make its graph by using `plot`. I tried using `trimf` but the output does not seem to be the plot that I want.

[image: plot that i make]

Comment: what is bad with the plot?

Comment: the plot look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/87rpl.jpg , and i think its not looklike fuzzy plot

Comment: Well.. they all should sum 1 at the support part. Yes?,... No?

Comment: Yes. i think all of 3 br, n and bl, should reach 1and have triangle shape

Comment: So which is the question then? Make it happen....

Answer (score 0):

Use this, each membership function equally sized and plotted all together:

```
plot([br' n' bl']);
```